# Foreign key constraints fails even if I disable FOREIGN_KEY_CHECK in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, binlog

I'm working with MySQL v8.0.16.
I have a binlog file from MySQL server A that I want to load in my MySQL server B. Server B has the same schemas as A, but not the data. When I attempt to load the parsed binlog file (generated using `mysqlbinlog 000004.binlog`) with this command:

```bash
mysql -uuser -p -e "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; show variables like 'foreign_key_checks'; source /tmp/parsed.binlog;"
```

It prints the following message:

```
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| foreign_key_checks | OFF   |
+--------------------+-------+

ERROR 1216 (23000) at line 43 in file: '/tmp/parsed.binlog': Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Why it doesn't ignore foreign key constraints?

Comment: Does a line in the file `parsed.binlog` turn foreign key checks back on?

Comment: @BillKarwin I found this line: `SET @@session.foreign_key_checks=1, @@session.sql_auto_is_null=0, @@session.unique_checks=1, @@session.autocommit=1/*!*/;` and I remove the `@@session.foreign_key_checks=1, `. Even though the problem persist, the output is the same.

Comment: Keep looking in the file. The line is likely repeated.

Comment: *ERROR 1216 (23000) at **line 43** in file:* - insert `show variables like 'foreign%';` into your file before this line and look for the output..

Comment: Using a binlog is probably not the best way to populate a Replica.  Instead use mysqldump.